# Google App Engine with Multiple Folders PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am having trouble getting my script in a different folder to work. Very new to Google App Engine, totally new to YAML.

The folder structure is:

```
/login.php
/includes/mySQLConnection.php
```

app.yaml

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /includes
  static_dir: includes
  application_readable: true
- url: /login.php
  script: login.php
```

login.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    if($_POST) {
    //Get Username and Password
    $user_email = strip_tags(trim(strtolower($_POST['username'])));
    $user_password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['password']));

    //Connect to mySQL Server
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."includes/mySQL_connection.php";

    // //Select which database to work with
    $database = mysql_select_db("test",$mySQL_connection) or die("Cannot connect to user table");

            echo json_encode(array('success' => 1,'error_message' => "Success"));
    }
?>
```

/includes/mySQL_connection.php

```
<?php
    $hostname = '127.0.0.1:3306'; 
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = '';

    //connection to the database
    $mySQL_connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
?>
```

This will not work, however if I take all the code out of /includes/mySQL_connection.php and put it into /login.php then it works perfectly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

DOCUMENT_ROOT does not have a trailing '/', looks like you'll need to add one.

In http://php-minishell.appspot.com/ I tried it out

```
>>> echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
/base/data/home/apps/s~php-minishell/20140319.374522287571266149
```

So probably change your code to

```
   //Connect to mySQL Server
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/mySQL_connection.php";
```